# Split URL into params

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I'm having trouble splitting the url into the following format for my URL.

Url = ?Point%20Cook-VIC-3030

desired format: Point Cook, VIC, 3030

So far I've tried the below to get rid of the "-" but I'm not sure how to get rid of the "?" and "%" and "20"

```
  const url = "?Point%20Cook-VIC-3030"
  const queryParams = url.split("-")
```

I tried using URLSearchParams but realized it doesn't have browser support for older browsers
which is a bummer

Comment: The `%20` is from the space being URI encoded. So, how about stripping the first character of the whole  string, before splitting it on the hyphen/dash, and then mapping on each of the items URI decoding them?

Comment: `unescape(url.substr(1)).split("-")`

Comment: @Bravo—yes, but the modern way is [*decodeURIComponent*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent). I'd do `decodeURIComponent('Point%20Cook-VIC-3030').replace('-',', ')`. :-)

Comment: @RobG - actually, the modern way would use URLSearchParams, then the `?` is taken care of for you - in this case, you'd only have a key though, but it's how I would do it - I also wouldn't have search params that are not key/value pairs, but I guess you can't mandate that on other peoples API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your URL is encoded (due to space character) you need to properly decode it.

```
const url = '?Point%20Cook-VIC-3030';
// Decode URL and remove initial '?'
const decodedUrl = decodeURIComponent(url).substring(1);
// Split parameters
const paramerters = decodedUrl.split('-');
```

Comment: thanks @JScoobyCed this is exactly what I needed!